# the difference between "must have + (past participle)" and "should have + (past participle)"

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, modal-verbs

The following is a question from the university entrance examination held in 2013 using the DNC Japan Test.

My brother (  ) have been very popular when he was a high school student.
He still gets lots of New Year's cards from his former classmates.

(1) must, (2) ought to, (3)should, (4) would

The correct answer is (1).
I wonder why (3)*should* can't be a correct answer.
If *must* is an answer, *should* must be another answer,
because both *must* and *should* have the meaning of necessity.

Comment: **Ven** I'm guessing is your way of saying V (erb) and the suffix -en, but that would exclude most verbs that are either regular or have different suffixes e.g. "She **must have played** well, if she won the tournament.” and "He says he's lost his glasses, but he **must have put** them somewhere.” It's **must / should + have + PP** (past participle)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, thank you. I am glad to have your comment again. This is the first time in (perhaps) three years that I have posted my question to this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Both *must* and *should* have the meaning of necessity" - but *must have* and *should have* have different meanings.

*He must have been very popular* = It's extremely likely that he was popular.

*He should have been very popular* = It seemed likely at the time that he would be popular (with the expected continuation *...but in fact he was not.*)

Comment: thank you for your help. So, "must have +(past participle)" means a deduction based on current evidence, and "should have + (past participle)" means a deduction in the past based on evidence at the time.  Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right - though perhaps an _expectation_ in the past rather than a deduction.

Comment: @Kate Bunting  I'm not sure that is quite it.  'Must have" is, interestingly, the opposite not of 'mustn't have' but of 'can't have'.  So yes, 'extremely likely' but with a feeling of 'surely it can't have been otherwise'.  'should have been' often means 'ought to have been' as in "Caruthers should have been head boy <but Grabber Major got it because his Dad gave money for the new chrcket pavillion>."